# How to determine if integer K is a member of an infinite integer series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers

Suppose I have an infinite integer series like $Q=4N-3$ where $N = 1,2,3\dots$
In this case the series values Q are $1,5,9,$ etc.
Is there a way to determine if an integer $K$ is a member of this series without testing each $N$ until $Q > K$?
In this example, all of the $Q$ are odd so even integers are obviously eliminated. However, try a large odd $K$ like $K=1,111,111.$
One possibility is to find an initial $N$ that puts $Q$ fairly close to $K$. Then adjust $N$ (up or down as needed) until either $Q=K$ or $Q$ jumps over $K$. However, is there a one-step (exact) solution that avoids the hunting?
(I am using this series as an example but I would like a general solution for any integer series.)

Thanks,
Don C.

Comment: For $K=1,111,111$, subtract $3$ and divide by $4$: the answer is $277,777$, so it comes from $N=277,777$. "any" integer series is asking too much, but you can at least do the same for e.g. $Q=89 N +16$. Also I took the liberty of typing your question in MathJax: You can learn how to do so [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), a more complete reference can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In the example, add 3 to K and see whether the last 2 digits of K+3 form a number divisible by 4. There cannot be a "quick" general solution or algorithm for all series unless there is a proof that 1=0.  The OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences) might give you an idea of the great variety of such sequences.

Comment: Calvin & Daniel -- thanks to both.